# Extended selection list binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a listbox in my view.I have set the selection mode as extended so that user can press ctrl and multiselect listbox items .My listbox item has  IsSelected property,I want it to  set to true when an item is selected and false when its deselected.Here is my code

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  SelectionMode="Extended">

public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList
{
   get;
   set;
}

public class Item
{
     public bool IsSelected
     {
        get;
        set;    
     }
}

public Item SelectedItem
{
    get
    {   
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
     {
        _selectedItem=value;
        _selectedItem.IsSelected=true;      
      }
}
```

The isSelected is getting true in case of single selection but not working for multiple selection and also please suggest how can I set it to false when deselected.Iam using MVVM.Can it be done using style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style setter to bind `IsSelected` property of `ListBoxItem` to `IsSelected` property of `Item` :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ......
    ......
</ListBox>
```